# Failed to render a widget

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to hybris e-commerce software and trying to learn with the help of wiki documents provided with it. My boss gave a task to add a custom made widget by my colleague to the backoffice. That widget works fine for older version (6.0), however it doesn't work on newer version(6.4) and most specific, the backoffice failed to render that widget.

```
Failed to render widget [id='importexportbackoffice-perspective', 
definitionId='com.****.widgets.importexportbackofficewidget', 
message='null']
```

Also in the command prompt it throws a NullPointerException at WidgetControllers.initSettings. Probably I am not adding the .zul file in the correct configuration xml. I re-write it, but it is still the same mistake. Also deleted that .zul file to see if there is any change or new exception, but it is still the same old NullPointerException. I am really desperate !

Here is the stack trace:

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP13] [WidgetControllers] unable to load widget settings
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.WidgetControllers.initSettings(WidgetControllers.java:163) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.DefaultWidgetController.doBeforeComposeChildren(DefaultWidgetController.java:89) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.doBeforeComposeChildren(UiEngineImpl.java:997) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:937) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:940) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.createComponents(UiEngineImpl.java:1150) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents0(AbstractExecution.java:346) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents(AbstractExecution.java:307) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions.createComponents(Executions.java:176) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.createComponents(DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.java:473) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.AdminmodeWidgetEngine.createComponents(AdminmodeWidgetEngine.java:207) [cockpitadmin-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.java:212) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.AdminmodeWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(AdminmodeWidgetEngine.java:106) [cockpitadmin-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.components.Widgetslot.updateView(Widgetslot.java:83) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.components.Widgetslot.afterCompose(Widgetslot.java:75) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.AbstractChildrenContainerRenderer.newWidgetslotsAfterCompose(AbstractChildrenContainerRenderer.java:102) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.TabContainerRenderer.render(TabContainerRenderer.java:157) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.java:1502) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.AdminmodeWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(AdminmodeWidgetEngine.java:1121) [cockpitadmin-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.java:1464) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.components.Widgetchildren.updateChildren(Widgetchildren.java:65) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.components.Widgetchildren.afterCompose(Widgetchildren.java:53) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:946) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:940) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.createComponents(UiEngineImpl.java:1150) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents0(AbstractExecution.java:346) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents(AbstractExecution.java:307) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions.createComponents(Executions.java:176) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.createComponents(DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.java:473) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.AdminmodeWidgetEngine.createComponents(AdminmodeWidgetEngine.java:207) [cockpitadmin-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.java:212) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.AdminmodeWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(AdminmodeWidgetEngine.java:106) [cockpitadmin-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.components.Widgetslot.updateView(Widgetslot.java:83) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.components.Widgetslot.afterCompose(Widgetslot.java:75) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:946) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:940) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:940) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.createComponents(UiEngineImpl.java:1150) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents0(AbstractExecution.java:346) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents(AbstractExecution.java:307) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions.createComponents(Executions.java:176) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.createComponents(DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.java:473) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.AdminmodeWidgetEngine.createComponents(AdminmodeWidgetEngine.java:207) [cockpitadmin-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine.java:212) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.AdminmodeWidgetEngine.createWidgetView(AdminmodeWidgetEngine.java:106) [cockpitadmin-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.components.Widgetslot.updateView(Widgetslot.java:83) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.components.Widgetslot.afterCompose(Widgetslot.java:75) [cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:946) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:940) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:842) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:797) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:461) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:369) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:211) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:137) [zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) [servlet-api.jar:?]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:140) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:301) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:390) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:140) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.modules.spring.filter.ExternalModuleContextClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(ExternalModuleContextClassLoaderFilter.java:44) [cockpit-module-aggregator-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DynamicCatalogVersionActivationFilter.doFilter(DynamicCatalogVersionActivationFilter.java:90) [classes/:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DynamicCatalogVersionActivationFilter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2d468805.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DynamicCatalogVersionActivationFilter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$71b36f4c.doFilter(<generated>) [classes/:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.DataSourceSwitchingFilter.doFilter(DataSourceSwitchingFilter.java:70) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:99) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.doFilter(RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.java:101) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.TenantActivationFilter.doFilter(TenantActivationFilter.java:88) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:44) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:201) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:179) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:358) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:306) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452) [catalina.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.75]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.75]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.75]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]

ERROR [hybrisHTTP3] [DefaultCockpitWidgetEngine] Could not create widget view
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.DefaultWidgetController.getModel(DefaultWidgetController.java:144) ~[cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.DefaultWidgetController.initDragAndDropAwareness(DefaultWidgetController.java:357) ~[cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.DefaultWidgetController.doBeforeComposeChildren(DefaultWidgetController.java:91) ~[cockpitframework-6.4.0.0-RC14.jar:?]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.doBeforeComposeChildren(UiEngineImpl.java:997) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:937) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:940) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:895) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:777) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.createComponents(UiEngineImpl.java:1150) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents0(AbstractExecution.java:346) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents(AbstractExecution.java:307) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions.createComponents(Executions.java:176) ~[zk-8.0.4.2.jar:3.6.4]
```

Comment: Please add a stacktrace.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, when creating perspective